# Adding files from file manager

Tags: android, image, file, icons

I have file manager with the help of which user can add files to the application. I get the paths of the chosen files and put them to the list. I want to put icons of chosen files with titles to the application. I'm wondering how to implement it in a best way - with the help of Image class or to create my own objects and set icon to it drom drawable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with regular TextView.
This is my method where is a loop through the array of files which were chosen by the user and adding icon and name to the TextView:

```
public void addFiles()
 {

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.filesList);

    if(FileManagerActivity.resFiles != null)
    {
         for (File file: FileManagerActivity.resFiles)
          {
            View line = new View(this);
                line.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(1, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                line.setBackgroundColor(0xAA345556);
                informationView = new TextView(this);
                informationView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                informationView.setTextSize(16);
                informationView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                        0, R.drawable.file_icon, 0, 0);
                informationView.setText(file.getName().toString());
                layout.addView(informationView, 0);
                layout.addView(line, 1);

          }
      }

}
```